# Using the scale transfer function for the Point Gaussian representation in Paraview?

Tags: particle-system, particles, paraview, openfoam

I have run the cyclone case from the OpenFOAM tutorials and want to view it using the builtin paraFOAM viewer which is based on Paraview 5.4.0.

The simulation has a number of particles in the diameter range of [2e-5, 1e-4] and i would like to scale the size of particles with the diameter array provided with the results.

To do this i select the Point Gaussian representation for the lagrangian fields (kinematiccloud), select Advanced properties, and select 'Scale by data array' after which the diameter array is chosen by default (although its not possible to change it to another field, which I suspect is a bug) but all the particles disappear from the view, as can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

My guess is that i need to chose proper values of the Gaussian radius and for the scale transfer function but there is no documentation to which it should be set. I have tried trial-and-error but i cannot find any settings for which i can get the particles back and have them render at different sizes.

Can someone enlighten me on how to set the Gaussian radius and scale transfer function properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PointGaussian has just been improved and configuration is now automatic. You may want to try the last release of ParaView.

More info here :
https://blog.kitware.com/major-improvements-on-the-point-gaussian-representation/